# What's the difference between path.resolve and path.join?

Tags: node.js

Is there some difference between the following invocations?

```
path.join(__dirname, 'app')
```

vs.

```
path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')
```

Which one should be preferred?

Comment: This question is [being discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381607/8186898) on meta

Answer (score 434, accepted):

The two functions deal with segments starting with `/` in very different ways; `join` will just concatenate it with the previous argument, however `resolve` will treat this as the root directory, and ignore all previous paths - think of it as the result of executing `cd` with each argument:

```
path.join('/a', '/b') // Outputs '/a/b'

path.resolve('/a', '/b') // Outputs '/b'
```

Another thing to note is that `path.resolve` will always result in an absolute URL, and will use your working directory as a base to resolve this path. But as `__dirname` is an absolute path anyway this doesn't matter in your case.

As for which one you should use, the answer is: it depends on how you want segments starting in `/` to behave - should they be simply joined or should they act as the new root?

If the other arguments are hard coded it really doesn't matter, in which case you should probably consider (a) how this line might change in future and (b) how consistent is it with other places in the code.

Comment: If you still don't get it: `path.join('/a', '/b', 'c')` will return `/a/b/c`, while `path.resolve('/a', '/b', 'c')` will return `/b/c`.

Comment: I would say the name of `resolve` is not the most clear, `path.cd([starting dir], [final dir])` would be much more intuitive.

Comment: The `think of it as the result of executing cd with each argument` made me finally understand it. Thanks

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira, I have updated the answer above as you have made a valid point. :)

Comment: so path.resolve => resolve path considering the working directory as the path starting point ?

Comment: To anyone wondering, a path starting with `/` means the ROOT directory of the filesystem. If I'm in `C:/folder` and redirect to `folder2` or `./folder2` (`.` means current directory), I will end up at `C:/folder/folder2`. If I now, from folder2, navigate to `/folder3` (notice only the forward slash at the start), I will **NOT** end up at `C:/folder/folder2/folder3`, but AT: `C:/folder3` (assuming such a folder exists). The difference being discussed here is that `path.join` will not give special treatment to a leading `/` to mean root directory, but `path.resolve` will do that. :)

Answer (score 54):

**1) path.resolve creates the absolute path.**

The method creates absoulte path **from right to left** until an absolute path is constructed.

For example:

```
path.resolve('/a', 'b', 'c');     //    C:\a\b\c
path.resolve('/a', '/b', 'c');    //    C:\b\c
path.resolve('/a', '/b', '/c');   //    C:\c
```

If absolute path is not generated, the method using current working directory:

For example:

```
path.resolve('a', 'b', 'c');     //    C:\{current_working_directory}\a\b\c
```

**2) path.join joins all path and the normalize the result**

For example:

```
path.join('/a', '/b', '/c');   //   \a\b\c
path.join('/a', '/b', 'c');    //   \a\b\c
path.join('/a', 'b', 'c');     //   \a\b\c
path.join('a', 'b', 'c');      //   a\b\c
```

EDIT: updated example above suggested by @spmdc

Comment: The last join example `path.join('a','b','c')` should result in `a\b\c`.

Comment: its mean automatically when use windows or linux ?

Answer (score 44):

The default operations of file system path vary based on the operating system we need some thing that abstract it.
The `path` module provides utilities or API for working with file and directory
paths.
you can include it in your project using

```
const path = require('path');
```

The `path.join` and `path.resolve` are two different methods of the path module.

Both these methods accept a sequence of paths or path segments.

The `path.resolve()` method resolves a sequence of paths or path segments into an *absolute path*.

The `path.join()` method joins all given path segments together using the platform specific separator as a delimiter, then normalizes the resulting path.

In order to better understand and differentiate behaviours, let me explain it with different scenarios.

**1. If we don't supply any arguments to or empty string**

in my case, my filename is `index.js` and the current working directory is `E:\MyFolder\Pjtz\node`

```
const path = require('path');

console.log("path.join() : ", path.join());
// outputs .
console.log("path.resolve() : ", path.resolve());
// outputs current directory or equalent to __dirname of the node process
```

and on running result is as below

```
λ node index.js
path.join() :  .
path.resolve() :  E:\MyFolder\Pjtz\node
```

*The inference from above experiment is tha `path.resolve()` method will output the **absolute path** where as the `path.join()` returns . representing the current working directory or **relative path** if nothing is provided*

**2. Adding a /path as any of arguments.**

```
const path=require('path');

console.log("path.join() : " ,path.join('abc','/bcd'));
console.log("path.resolve() : ",path.resolve('abc','/bcd'));
```

and the result is

```
λ node index.js
path.join() :  abc\bcd
path.resolve() :  E:\bcd
```

*The inference we can found with this experiment is that `path.join()` only concatenates the input list with platform specific separator while the `path.resolve()` process the sequence of paths from right to left, with each subsequent path prepended until an absolute path is constructed.*

`path.join()` concatenates each argument with OS specific separators while `path.resolve()` will resolve each argument with root and produce output.

Comment: `path.resolve()` is **not equivalent** to `__dirname`. The first returns the working directory, while the second is the path to the current file.

Comment: @EmileBergeron In my understanding both of them are the functions on path. You can try following snippet to check wheter both are same i think.
`const path = require('path');
console.log(path.resolve())
console.log(__dirname)
console.log(path.resolve()===__dirname)`

Comment: They happen to be the same only when the file being run is in the current working directory.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Ok that i agree.But Iam still confused on where i specified `path.resolve() is equivalent to __dirname`

Comment: In a comment below the first point you make in the answer. `// outputs current directory or equalent to __dirname`

Comment: It's still true in your case, it's just misleading or confusing. I feel it should read `// outputs current directory, equalent to __dirname in this specific case`

Comment: @EmileBergeron i had updated the comment i think it wil resolve the confussion

Answer (score 14):

## In Simplest` Terms:

`path.resolve()` just does the following

`from left to right-`

- concatenate the right most parameters with `/` directly with the root path to make an absolute path (check the examples)
- and then concatenates anything without `/` as a directory

using sergey's example

```
path.resolve('/a', 'b', 'c');     returns    C:\a\b\c
path.resolve('/a', '/b', 'c');    returns    C:\b\c
path.resolve('/a', '/b', '/c');   returns    C:\c
```

While `join` simply concatenates every parameter from left to right whether they have `/` or not

```
path.join("/a", "b", "/c", "d")   simply returns   "\a\b\c\d"
```

Comment: I think this answer is miss-leading the processing steps should be from "right to left" of all segments. It stops until it reach an absolute path.  https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathresolvepaths

Answer (score 0):

`path.join` concatenates all parameters from left to right, the return value can be a relative path or absolute path.

`path.resolve` returns an absolute path. Besides, I quote this from the book **Professional Node.js: Building Javascript Based Scalable Software** written by Pedro Teixeira (2012 edition):

> You can resolve a series of paths into a normalized absolute path by using `path.resolve()`. **It works like an iterative `cd` command for every argument**, except that it also works on files and it's abstract - it does not tap into the underlying fi lesystem to try to see if the path exists; it simply
> manipulates paths.

I find this explanation very straightforward, so I would like to post it as an answer.