# path.join vs path.resolve with __dirname

Tags: node.js

Is there a difference when using *both* `path.join` and `path.resolve` with `__dirname` for resolving absolute path in Node.js?

Should one of them be preferred when being used like that (absolute path resolutions are 90% of use cases)?

I.e.

```
const absolutePath = path.join(__dirname, some, dir);
```

vs.

```
const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, some, dir);
```

Both methods normalize path.

Comment: This question is [being discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381607/8186898) on meta

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between path.resolve and path.join invocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048686/difference-between-path-resolve-and-path-join-invocation)

Comment: Seems the accepted answer removed

Comment: @user202729 It stated that the main difference is that path.join doesn't normalize paths, which is not true. I removed this disclaimer, the accepted answer in that question has been changed since then to a correct one.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Yes there is a difference between the functions but the way you are using them in this case will result in the same outcome.

`path.join` returns a normalized path by merging two paths together. It can return an absolute path, but it doesn't necessarily always do so.

For instance:

```
path.join('app/libs/oauth', '/../ssl')
```

resolves to `app/libs/ssl`

`path.resolve`, on the other hand, will resolve to an absolute path.

For instance, when you run:

```
path.resolve('bar', '/foo');
```

The path returned will be `/foo` since that is the first absolute path that can be constructed.

However, if you run:

```
path.resolve('/bar/bae', '/foo', 'test');
```

The path returned will be `/foo/test` again because that is the first absolute path that can be formed from right to left.

If you don't provide a path that specifies the root directory then the paths given to the `resolve` function are appended to the current working directory. So if your working directory was `/home/mark/project/`:

```
path.resolve('test', 'directory', '../back');
```

resolves to

`/home/mark/project/test/back`

Using `__dirname` is the absolute path to the directory containing the source file. When you use `path.resolve` or `path.join` they will return the same result if you give the same path following `__dirname`. In such cases it's really just a matter of preference.

Comment: Nit: `__dirname` is the absolute path to the directory containing the source file that is being executed, not the *current working directory*.  The former will always be the same (unless you move the file); the latter is a [process-wide parameter](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) that varies based on how you launched node and whether or not you've [changed it](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory).

Comment: So is there no difference between ```__dirname``` and ```path.resolve(__dirname)```?

Comment: @georaldc: I found one: node <<<"path=require('path'); console.log(__dirname); console.log(path.resolve(__dirname))"

Comment: Fixed the issue with __dirname in the answer per @josh3736

Comment: I hate to say it, but this answer really doesn't make any sense to me and I would appreciate some clarification. You remark that `path.resolve('/bar/bae', '/foo', 'test');` essentially discards the first argument because `/foo/test` "is the first absolute path that can be formed from right to left," but you didn't explain *why*, so I really don't understand the logic at work. I mean I don't have any view into the hypothetical directory structure you're using in your example, so I can't conceive of why `/bar/bae/foo/test` is invalid.

Comment: @temporary_user_name The answer is correct regarding `path.resolve`'s behaviour here: `path.resolve` operates from the right-most argument, moving left-wards through the argument list and prepending each argument's value until an absolute path (i.e. one beginning with the root directory `/` or [in Windows specifically] a drive letter) is constructed, then returns that path. It ignores `/bar/bae` because by that point, it already has the absolute path `/foo/test` and therefore sees no reason to go further.

Comment: This answer creates more confusing than it resolve.

Comment: This is not a direct answer,  but may avoid some confusion. If you started your *process* with `node app.js`, then `__dirname` is the directory location of `app.js` -- the *currently executing* file.  Whichever file you call `resolve` or `join` from is in the `./` directory for that file.

Answer (score 39):

```
const absolutePath = path.join(__dirname, some, dir);
```

vs.

```
const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, some, dir);
```

`path.join` will concatenate `__dirname` which is the directory name of the current file concatenated with values of `some` and `dir` with platform-specific separator.

Whereas

`path.resolve` will process `__dirname`, `some` and `dir` i.e. from right to left prepending it by processing it.

**If any of the values of `some` or `dir` corresponds to a root path then the previous path will be omitted and process rest by considering it as root**

In order to better understand the concept let me explain both a little bit more detail as follows:-

The `path.join` and `path.resolve` are two different methods or functions of the path module provided by nodejs.

Where both accept a list of paths but the difference comes in the result i.e. how they process these paths.

`path.join` concatenates all given path segments together using the platform-specific separator as a delimiter, then normalizes the resulting path. While the `path.resolve()` process the sequence of paths from right to left, with each subsequent path prepended until an absolute path is constructed.

**When no arguments supplied**

The following example will help you to clearly understand both concepts:-

My filename is `index.js` and the current working directory is `E:\MyFolder\Pjtz\node`

```
const path = require('path');

console.log("path.join() : ", path.join());
// outputs .
console.log("path.resolve() : ", path.resolve());
// outputs current directory or equivalent to __dirname
```

Result

```
λ node index.js
path.join() :  .
path.resolve() :  E:\MyFolder\Pjtz\node
```

*`path.resolve()` method will output the absolute path whereas the `path.join()` returns . representing the current working directory if nothing is provided*

**When some root path is passed as arguments**

```
const path=require('path');

console.log("path.join() : " ,path.join('abc','/bcd'));
console.log("path.resolve() : ",path.resolve('abc','/bcd'));
```

Result i

```
λ node index.js
path.join() :  abc\bcd
path.resolve() :  E:\bcd
```

*`path.join()` only concatenates the input list with platform-specific separator while the `path.resolve()` process the sequence of paths from right to left, with each subsequent path prepended until an absolute path is constructed.*

Comment: The question was specifically about *path.join vs path.resolve **with __dirname***.

Comment: I had updated answer based on your comments thanks for the update

Answer (score 9):

From the doc for `path.resolve`:

> The resulting path is normalized and trailing slashes are removed unless the path is resolved to the root directory.

But `path.join` keeps trailing slashes

So

```
__dirname = '/';
path.resolve(__dirname, 'foo/'); // '/foo'
path.join(__dirname, 'foo/'); // '/foo/'
```

Comment: what is the word 'normalized' mean in this context ?

Comment: @apollo [path.normalize(path)](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_path)

Comment: @apollo: `root/folder1/../folder1/./folder2/../../folder1` normalized is: `root/folder1`, essentially shaving off all the unnecessary stuff and keeping it nice and tidy ;)

Answer (score 5):

**In Simplest` Terms:**

When you use `path.resolve()` It returns the **absolute** path as follows

`from left to right-`

- concatenate the right most parameters with `/` directly with the root path to make an absolute path (check the examples)
- and then concatenates anything to the right without `/` as a directory

for example

```
path.resolve('/a', 'b', 'c');     returns    C:\a\b\c
path.resolve('/a', '/b', 'c');    returns    C:\b\c
path.resolve('/a', '/b', '/c');   returns    C:\c
```

---

While using `join()` simply concatenates every parameter from left to right whether they have `/` or not

```
path.join("/a", "b", "/c", "d")   simply returns   "\a\b\c\d"
```

Comment: *directly with the root path to make an absolute path* - it doesn't just concatenate but actually considers /a and /b absolute paths, Unix ones are prepended with current disk letter on Windows.