# path.join does not work?

Tags: node.js, path, filepath

I want to read from a path and I wrote two different codes.The first code does not work but the second code works perfectly. I do not understand the differences. can someone explain to me what is going on? thanks.
 the file is stored in /modules/config/

First Code:

```
var tmpModulePath = path.join('./modules/',"config/");
var moduleConfigInfo = require(tmpModulePath + "_test.js");
```

Second code:

```
var tmpModulePath = path.join('./modules/',"config/");
var moduleConfigInfo = require("./" + tmpModulePath + "_test.js");
```

from the first code, I do get this error: Can not find module ..._tset.csv

Comment: The question lacks enough information. The full code is needed and better information. Also you can see the difference between the two code you pasted.

Comment: @ Griffin, it is updated now. hope it is clear enough now!!!

Comment: Try `console.log(path.join('./modules/',"config/"))` and you will find that `path.join` drops `./` at the beginning. Without it, `require` doesn't try to load a module from the current directory.

Comment: As the error mentions, it cannot find `_test.csv` in given path `./modules/config/`. But it can find it in path `././modules/config/`. Reason is simple. It does not exist in first path and it does exits in second path given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you console.log the generated path you get this results:

First code block:

"modules/config/_test.js"

Second code block:

"./modules/config/_test.js"

In the second case, you have a relative path starting from your current directory (`./`). `require` will look for a modules folder starting from your current directory.

In the first case, the path is absolute, meaning that `require` will look for a `modules` folder starting from the root path of your filesystem.

I hope you understand the difference now.

What you really want to use in this case is `path.resolve`:

```
var tmpModulePath1 = path.resolve('./', 'modules/',"config/", 'test.js');
```

Check the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110801/path-join-vs-path-resolve-with-dirname) to understand the difference between `.join` and `.resolve`.

Comment: @ pietrovismara, sorry for the bad example. it is a .js file. I problem is i dont understand why "./" does not work in the fisrt format

Comment: @ pietrovismara, you answer is quite clear, but with resolve(), i dont get the last "/" in the path. I wanted to have the full path with the "/" at the end

Comment: if it's `modules/config/_test.js`, will it not look within the `node_modules` directory instead of the root path of the filesystem ?