# create-react-app can't resolve module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, es6-modules

I"m upgrading a older react application to use the latest and greatest, but I can't seem to figure out why just about all my modules wont resolve.

[image]

It seems at some point you could simply point to a folder in a import and now it no longer resolves

In my Webpack I believe I have it setup correctly. Anyone know what changed with imports?

```js
resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/253
    modules: ["node_modules", paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean),
      path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
    ),
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/290
    // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
    // for React Native Web.
    extensions: [
      ".web.js",
      ".mjs",
      ".js",
      ".json",
      ".web.jsx",
      ".jsx",
      ".scss",
      ".css",
      ".json"
    ]
```

Comment: I see. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem. This could be anything. There's no single point of responsibility for imports, especially since it's your custom Webpack config.

Comment: either change it to `src/common/eventemitter/.....` or use relative path from current file, like `../../eventemitter/.....`

Comment: import EventEmitter from "../../eventemitter"; works, but since I added my src directory to resolve: shouldnt I be able to use it similar to a node module ??

Would I need to alias it in my resolve to something like internal then do
import EventEmitter from ''internal/common/eventemitter

Comment: Ok, try changing `path.resolve(__dirname, "src")` to `path.resolve(__dirname, "./src")`. Or try path.join instead of path.resolve.

Comment: @Kartik There's no difference, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110801/path-join-vs-path-resolve-with-dirname

Comment: I moved path.resolve(__dirname, "src") before "node_modules" and it worked. even more confused now

Comment: @Jesse It's unknown what exactly was upgraded. Was it Webpack? The problem is specific to Webpack, the question didn't had this tag. FWIW, `resolve.alias` is much more common, e.g. `@app/common/...`. Import like `common/...` looks really confusing and ambiguous - just because there's `common` package but no `@app/common` on NPM.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was a simple matter of my render not having the correct path for my src directory

Answer (score 0):

The problem was path.resolve(__dirname, "src")  didnt appear to be resolving to what I thought it was.

```js
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

 module.exports = {
  dotenv: resolveApp('.env'),
  appBuild: resolveApp('build'),
  appPublic: resolveApp('public'),
  appHtml: resolveApp('public/index.html'),
  appIndexJs: resolveApp('src/main.jsx'),
  appPackageJson: resolveApp('package.json'),
  appSrc: resolveApp('src'),
  yarnLockFile: resolveApp('yarn.lock'),
  testsSetup: resolveApp('src/setupTests.js'),
  appNodeModules: resolveApp('node_modules'),
  publicUrl: getPublicUrl(resolveApp('package.json')),
  servedPath: getServedPath(resolveApp('package.json')),
};


modules: ["node_modules", paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean),
      paths.appSrc
    ),
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/290
    // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
    // for React Native Web.
    extensions: [
      ".web.js",
      ".mjs",
      ".js",
      ".json",
      ".web.jsx",
      ".jsx",
      ".scss",
      ".css",
      ".json"
    ]
```