# Path Problems when Creating bunyan Child Logger

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, npm, bunyan

In this simple app where two different files `foo.js` and `bar.js` imports `Logger.js` to create a `bunyan` child logger.

**Problem:** `foo.js` works flawlessly but `bar.js` has a problem finding `MyService.log` defined in `Logger.js`. This appears to be due to the relative path to `MyService.log` being fixed, while `foo.js` and `bar.js` resides in different directory levels relative to the project root directory.

What will be a better way to create `bunyan` child logger?

```
.
├── lib
|   └── Logger.js
├── foo
|   └── foo.js
├── bar.js
```

**/src/lib/Logger.js**

```
const bunyan = require('bunyan')
const logger = bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'MyService',
    streams: [
        {
            stream: process.stdout,
            level: "info"
        },
        {
            type: 'rotating-file',
            path: '../logs/MyService.log',
            period: '1w',
            count: 100,
            level: "debug"
        }
    ]
})

module.exports = {
    getChildLogger(componentName) {
        return logger.child({
            component: componentName
        })
    }
}
```

**/src/foo/foo.js**

```
const log = require('../lib/Logger').getChildLogger('foo')
log.info('Foo')
```

**/src/bar.js**

```
const log = require('./lib/Logger').getChildLogger('foo')
log.info('Bar')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of relative path, try using absolute file path using path module (core).

```
const path = require('path');

const loggerPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'logs', 'MyService.log');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `resolve` method from `path` module. The selected answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110801/path-join-vs-path-resolve-with-dirname/39111164) highlights the advantage of `resolve` method:

> If you don't provide a path that specifies the root directory then the
>   paths given to the resolve function are appended to the current
>   working directory.

So I would specify the path as:

```
const { resolve } = require('path');

const log = resolve('logs', 'MyService.log');
```