# Webpack resolve.alias not working in node/server side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, webpack-4

I want to test my dependency in main repo before publishing that component. So that I used `webpack.resolve.alias` all seems good in client side but not working in server side. In server side, still it is referring `node_modules` instead of alias path. In my webpack config, i have 2 bundles(Server and Client).

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@select/components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../components/packages/components/src'),
    react: path.join(__dirname, "../node_modules/react"),
    "react-dom": path.join(__dirname, "../node_modules/react-dom"),
    "styled-components": path.join(__dirname, "../node_modules/styled-components")
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use path.resolve for all aliases:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@select/components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../components/packages/components/src'),
    'react': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/react'),
    'react-dom': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/react-dom'),
    'styled-components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/styled-components')
  }
},
```

Technically,  both `join` and `resolve` with `__dirname` should give the same results but my personal preference is to use `path.resolve` for aliases.

There is a good explanation about [join vs resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110801/path-join-vs-path-resolve-with-dirname/39111164).

Comment: Already using path.resolve in '@select/components'. Still not working

Comment: Could you, please, share how your component is imported in the code?

Comment: import { Component } from '@select/components';