# fs-extra not removing files inside directory

Tags: node.js, async-await, prisma, fs-extra

I'm using fs-extra library to delete some image files on post request in my node js app. every time I call /deleteproduct route everything works fine. my product is removed from database and fs-extra callback doesn't throw any error even though files are not removed! I don't know what is the reason. I think maybe I'm doing something wrong with async/await functions.

this is my code:

```
router.post('/deleteproduct', async (req, res) => {
try {
  const id = req.body.id;

  const deleteProduct = await prisma.product.findUnique({
    where: { id: id }
  });

  const images = JSON.parse(deleteProduct.image);

  for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    await fsExtra.remove(path.join(__dirname, `public/images/${images[i]}`), (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });
    console.log(images[i]);
  }

  await prisma.product.delete({
    where: { id: id }
  });

  res.status(200).json({ msg: "Deleted product with id: " + id });
} catch (error) {
  res.json({ msg: error });  
}

});
```

**EDIT:** image files are inside images folder in public directory.

[directory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wEfy.png)

**please comment if you need more info**

directories image:

[directories image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVQJw.png)

**cpanel.js** is deleting the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be two problems here. First, your are not using correct path to reference your files correctly. Secondly, you are using await and callbacks at the same time. You can do something like this.

```
try {
const images = JSON.parse(deleteProduct.image);
const imageProm = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
     imageProm.push(fsExtra.remove(path.join(__dirname, `public/images/${images[i]}`)
    
  }
  const result = await Promise.all(imageProm);
  await prisma.product.delete({
    where: { id: id }
  });

}

catch (e) {console.log(e)}
```

If the above solution doesn't work why can't you use `fs.unlink` a native method provided to work for such scenarios. Try using that.

Note: whenever you use async/await use try/catch block to catch errors.

Comment: It turned out I was using wrong path. I will add a new image of my directories to the question. can you please explain why using `public/images/${images[i]}` instead of path.join(__dirname, `public/images/${images[i]}`) works?

Comment: you should check this for [path.join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110801/path-join-vs-path-resolve-with-dirname). You can also upvote it thanks!

Comment: I can't upvote because I have 7 reputations. I'm new to stack overflow. thank you for the answer. I'll upvote after I reach 15 reputations

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
await fsExtra.remove(path.join(__dirname, `public/images/${images[i]}`), (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });
```

Could you directly try this:

```
await fsExtra.remove(path.join(__dirname, `public/images/${images[i]}`));
```

`fs-extra` returns a promise so this should work. Adding a `try/catch` to check for errors can also be implemented

Comment: images array contains name of the files: productImages-1623766133740.jpg