# Why is express' res.download() method causing a "request aborted" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, download

I have the following code from a `node.js` server that uses the `express` framework:

```
var fs = require('fs')
    express = require('express')
    handlebars = require('express-handlebars');

var helpers = require('./lib/helpers');

var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next){
   var pathUrl = req.path; 
   if(pathUrl !== '/')
   res.download(__dirname + '/' + 'download.png', 'download.png', function(err){
      console.log(err);
   });
   next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.send('<a href=' + '/download.png' + '>' + 'download' + '</a>');
});

app.listen(3001);
```

When run, this code creates the following error:

```
{ Error: Request aborted
    at onaborted (/home/js/webdev/fs/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1021:15)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/home/js/webdev/fs/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1063:9)
    at runCallback (timers.js:696:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:667:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:649:5) code: 'ECONNABORTED' }
```

If `res.download()` changes on to `res.send('Helo')`, it works.

Why does `res.download()` not work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You're not allowing `res.download()` to finish

The `Error: Request aborted` means that express hasn't had a chance to finish sending what it needs to send.

When you call `res.download()`, it's equivalent to performing `res.send()` except making sure it has adequate headers for the browser to know it's a file download, instead of something to display in the browser. This function call is *asynchronous*, meaning that it will continue running in the background and then run the next line of code, which in this case, is `next()`.

`next()` gets called, which then tells express to continue looking for routes that match, or, in this case, there are no more routes that match and express will **terminate the connection**. This is *not* what you want, as you're still trying to finish the file download. You don't need express tell you when you're done, *you say when you're done*.

#### How to fix it?

Very simply, just make sure that express *cannot* continue to the next route in the middleware if the route isn't `/`. Add an `else` clause to your conditional:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   var pathUrl = req.path;
   if(pathUrl !== '/') {
       res.download(__dirname + '/' + 'download.png', 'download.png', function(err){
          console.log(err);
       });
   } else {
       next();
   }
});
```

---

### Footnote

This is not the easiest way to accomplish what you're trying to do here. You can use wildcard route matching (`*`) to make this much simpler. I've given your code a little tidy up that includes some of these features.

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send(`<a href="/download.png">download</a>`));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.download(path.join(__dirname, "./download.png"), "download.png", err => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
});

app.listen(3001);
```

- `(req, res) => {}` is a [cleaner way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) of writing `function(req, res) {}`
- the `path` module [should be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048686/difference-between-path-resolve-and-path-join-invocation) as it can handle multiple OS's
- the `*` wildcard route will match anything, and should usually always go last
- we now check to see if there is an `err` before we `console.log()` it

Comment: I'm also facing an issue where after calculating and saving 999999 records in csv file, at the time of res.download this error occurs and the route initiate again