# res.download() throws 'request aborted' error when downloading large files

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, nginx, amazon-s3

My MEAN stack app requires a feature where users can select any number of files from a list of files available on s3, which are then downloaded, zipped up, and returned to the user as a download. For extremely large files, the initial request would time out while larger files were being downloaded/zipped, so now there are 3 separate requests. The first request is a POST providing the list of files, which returns a token. Once this request returns, a second, constant polling GET request is sent using this token to determine if the download/zip is finished. This will fire once every second until it receives the desired response. Once the downloading and zipping of files is completed, a db entry is generated matching the provided token, which satisfies the second request, now the third and final request GET fires, which is a request to download the completed file.

```
function downloadZip( req: Request, res: Response, next: Function ) {

if ( !req.params.token ) {
    return next( new Error( "downloadZip requires token." ) );
}

icmDownloadModel.findByToken( req.params.token, ( err, data ) => {

    if ( err ) {
        return next( err );
    }

    if ( data && data.fileName && data.token ) {

        let localPath: string = path.join( __dirname, "..", "uploads", data.token + '.zip' );

        res.download( localPath, data.fileName, err => {

            if ( err ) {
                return next( err );
            }

            fs.unlink( localPath );

            icmDownloadModel.delete( data._id, ( err ) => {
                if ( err ) {
                    next( err );
                }
            });

        } );

    } else {

        next( new Error( "Unable to locate file." ) );
    }

} );
```

};

So far, this is working almost perfectly, however, when attempting to download files 1GB+, I get an error saying 'request aborted'. The files are successfully downloaded from s3 and zipped, but the res.download() craps out after a few seconds. I have managed to download files upwards of 250MB without issue. Also, this works fine on my local instance, but fails on the live DEV environment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is express' res.download() method causing a "request aborted" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995471/why-is-express-res-download-method-causing-a-request-aborted-error)

Comment: @stdunbar I came across that as well. I don't think this is the issue, as I am not calling next() outside of the callback.