# I am trying to download file using res.download(). I get the following error

Tags: node.js

```js
 const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs');

 const filePath1 = path.join
(
__dirname,
 "..",
 "public",
"exports",
"csv-"+ req.user.ecode + " history"  + ".csv"
)
  fs.writeFile(filePath1,csv,function(err){
            if(err){
              console.log('fs writeFile error:' + err)
              return res.status(500).json({ err })
            }else{
              setTimeout(function()
             {
             fs.unlinkSync(filePath1)
             },40000)
             res.download(filePath1, function(err){
                console.log(err);                     
              })
            }
          })
```

am getting the following output in my console with csv and error as follows.. 
Date :,Feb-14-2020
Strategy,Corporate Goal,Project Name,Weightage,Responsibility,Target Date
Financial,EBIDTA@582%= 46.77cr INR,Project A,10,EM00875,Jul-25-2020
Financial,EBIDTA@582%= 46.77cr INR,Project C,90,EM00875,Feb-16-2020

```
Error: Request aborted
    at onaborted (E:\KRA_5\abc_5_final - Copy\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1025:15)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (E:\KRA_5\abc_5_final - Copy\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1067:9)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21) {
  code: 'ECONNABORTED'
}
```

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995471/why-is-express-res-download-method-causing-a-request-aborted-error
Also do check request headers

Answer (score 0):

Download your file using Express.js instead of Node.js.
[How to download a file using Express in Node.js](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download)

Hopefully the problem will be fixed. Let me know.

Besides, you can check the following links to have more clear idea that can be helpful related to your problem.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20177012/10427807
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7288883/10427807