# How to send a file (Any type) to the frontend from the express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, express

I am taking a file which is stored on the server, and sending it to the frontend for download. So when the user hits this url, it the file should automatically download. And it is downloading  also. But the problem is the file recieved is corrupt. Like If I am sending some pdf from the server, I am getting  a corrupt pdf.

Let me explain what the code below does, it takes the unique id (uuid) from the url params and then searches for a file with that particular uuid, if the file is not there it sends an error, but if it is there, it searches for the file on the server using the uuid and the path mentioned the db doc, and then sends it to the frontend. But when I am downloading that file I am getting a corrupt file.

Also this happens when I hit this endpoint of the server which I hosted on heroku, but the file downloaded is not corrupt when I use the localhost...which I think is obvious.
Please help.

Code :

```
import express from 'express' ; 
import File from '../models/file.js' ; 
import path from 'path' ; 

const router = express.Router() ; 

router.get('/:uuid', async (req,res)=> {

    const file = await File.findOne({uuid: req.params.uuid});

    if(!file) return res.render('download', {error: "Link expire ho gya"});
    console.log(file)
    const __dirname = path.resolve();

    console.log(__dirname) ; 

    const filePath = `${__dirname}\\${file.path}`;
    console.log(filePath) ; 
    res.download(filePath) ; 
    

})

export default {router}
```

Comment: What type of data is in the file?  Does it have a typical file extension that indicates it's type?  Can you provide that filename (with no path) as the 2nd argument to `res.download()`?  If you attach a 3rd argument to `res.download()` for a callback, do you get an error to that callback?

Comment: Have you verified that the file is valid on the server before it is sent to the client?  Did you try either of those two things I mentioned with the 2nd and 3rd argument to `res.download()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 when I attached a callback as 3rd arg, I got an error "request aborted", and yes the file is a valid file, as the file is recieved from the client side and stored on the server, and then later fetched when the client hits this endpoint.

Comment: OK, this sounds like perhaps a heroku configuration setting or something like that which is limiting the size of file you can send or the duration of your http connection.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know much about heroku.  What level of account do you have at heroku?  If the Heroku infrastructure is causing this on purpose, then you should find something in your Heroku log that might have a Heroku error code you could look up.

Comment: There's no error code, I think the error is caused because of some type of interruption in the http connection with the client.

Comment: can you add  "{responseType: arraybuffer}" to the get request

Comment: @BerkeKaanCetinkaya {responseType: arraybuffer } in the frontend ? nvm the issue got solved. I referred this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995471/why-is-express-res-download-method-causing-a-request-aborted-error   Anyways thanks.

Comment: @MadhuPaka then please take the effort to share it as an answer to help future devs.