# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Self Project\react-shopper\react-shopper\client\build\index.html'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I have exactly followed the tutorial and the startup code from Reed Barger and whenever I try to run the server it always says this:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Self Project\react-shopper\react-shopper\client\build\index.html'`

I don't know but what caused this. I am not able to figure it out that why it is not creating the built file and shy there is such error. Below is the screen shot I have attached of the **index.js** file:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Use `path.join()` method instead of `resolve` in `sendFile`. It should work, If your file hierarchy is correct. [resolve and join methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048686/whats-the-difference-between-path-resolve-and-path-join) **read this question and answer may it will help you**

Comment: Thank you. I have tried using `path.join()` but it is still not working.