# Problem serving index.html from Express server, but not when I run client separately

Tags: reactjs, express

I have an app that is made using `ReactJS` and `ExpressJS`. The Express server is responsible for getting data, and ReactJS for displaying it. When I run them separately, meaning, I go into the root folder and start the server, and then go into client and start the React app, everything works fine, but when I try to serve the static index.html file I get an error.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'regular')**

This is how I'm serving the static file:

```
 app.get("*", (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client". "build", "index.html"));
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file structure is:

```
|root
   |client
      |build
   -server.js
```

then you need to specify the path as `__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"` and use join instead of resolve.

Comment: I already did that, same thing happened.

Comment: try join instead of resolve

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved my problem. Can you please explain why one worked and other didn't? Thanks.

Comment: resolve treats the first argument as the root of your directory. join just concatenates the arguments, then creates a string from them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048686/whats-the-difference-between-path-resolve-and-path-join