# Page reload or pasting url gives 404 with MERN stack

Tags: reactjs, express, http-status-code-404, reload, mern

I am building a simple website that uses MERN stack running on apache.
There is a proxy (& reverse proxy) settings on /api to route to ip:port/api

At some point in the last couple of months, any page refresh or pasting urls causes a 404. I cannot identify what causes this.

It is using client side routing (based  and it was working. It is still working on localhost only breaks on the server.

Now when I put the old code that used to work on the server, it breaks the same way. This suggests that a change in the environment is causing/contributing.

One developer I was working added this piece of code to try to address it.

```
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      // Set static folder
      app.use(express.static("client/build"));
    
      app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
      });
    
    }
```

It doesn't seem to have any effect even if I remove the if condition. I did a little test.

1. I added an image with name 'register'
2. If I go to my website and click on register it works
3. If I visit domain/register, it is showing the image, so even with the code snippet above it is treating it as a request for static file and not letting it pass on and resolve to the index.html

About the server

1. Ubuntu with Apache with proxy on /api to node server
2. Uses a self signed certificate but it breaks on http or https.

This seems to be a common problem. If anyone has seen this before or can give pointers on where to debug this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Trying this code worked for me. And refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048686/whats-the-difference-between-path-resolve-and-path-join) for the difference between path.resolve and path.join

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const root = path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build');
  app.use(express.static(root));
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root });
  })
}
```